# Sqlite converting time to seconds

Tags: sqlite

I have a query that produces columns Username,TotalPages,TotalTime,AveragePage

```
SELECT UserName,TotalPages,TotalTime,cast(strftime('%H',TotalTime)*3600 as integer) as AveragePerPage FROM
(
SELECT UID FROM DPS WHERE UID >0
)a
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT UID,UserName,COUNT(UserName) as TotalPages,cast((sum(strftime('%s', endtime) - strftime('%s', starttime))/3600)as varchar) || ":" || cast(((sum(strftime('%s', endtime) - strftime('%s', starttime))/60)%60)as varchar) || ":" || cast((sum(strftime('%s', endtime) - strftime('%s', starttime))%60)as varchar) as TotalTime FROM abbottTimer GROUP BY UID
)b ON a.UID = b.UID
GROUP BY a.UID
```

[image]

The row that have a single H produces a null value
but the double digit produces data. How can i do this. Im using sqlite.
EDIT:
Also how to compute it for HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT UserName,TotalPages,TotalTime,CAST(sum((TotalTime1/TotalPages)/3600) as varchar) || ":" || CAST(sum(((TotalTime1/TotalPages)/60)%60) as varchar) || ":" || CAST(sum((TotalTime1/TotalPages)%60) as varchar) as Averageperpage
                                  FROM
(
SELECT UID FROM DPS WHERE UID >0
)a
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT UID,UserName,COUNT(UserName) as TotalPages,cast((sum(strftime('%s', endtime) - strftime('%s', starttime))/3600)as varchar) || ":" || cast(((sum(strftime('%s', endtime) - strftime('%s', starttime))/60)%60)as varchar) || ":" || cast((sum(strftime('%s', endtime) - strftime('%s', starttime))%60)as varchar) as TotalTime,sum(STRFTIME('%s',endtime) - STRFTIME('%s',starttime)) as TotalTime1 FROM abbottTimer GROUP BY UID
)b ON a.UID = b.UID
GROUP BY a.UID
```

I just solved it. Divide the the integer with 3600 for hours and etc

Answer (score 1):

Supported [time strings](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) have two digits in all fields.

The built-in time functions cannot handle the values in your database. You must change them.

Answer (score -1):

You should show us the original `TotalTime` values stored in your database.
Also, did you read the [sqlite doc about `strftime`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) where you can use `%s` modifier to have your time returned as a number of seconds since 19700101.

I personnaly use `datetime(<myTime>, 'unixepoch')` when I work with date and time.

Comment: Its a Integer data type.

Comment: i tried the `strftime('%s',TotalTime)` but the same problem occured. The single hour like `8:34:32` produces null value

Comment: And what do you store in this integer? number of seconds since 1970?

Comment: the elapsed time of encoding.

Comment: in seconds I suppose. So you already have your time in seconds and doesn't have to do any conversion or multiplication by 3600.